# function computerTurn()

Tags: javascript

надеюсь это мой последний вопрос на эту тему

не работает функция `function computerTurn()` и у меня нет ни каких мыслей как  правильно написать эту функцию(он в самом конце кода), и тут выложил весь код.

Он должен после каждого хода человека поставить X или O, смотря из ситуации(ещё не добавлена возможность выбора первого хода, но она будет)

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById("s1")
var s2 = document.getElementById("s2")
var s3 = document.getElementById("s3")
var s4 = document.getElementById("s4")
var s5 = document.getElementById("s5")
var s6 = document.getElementById("s6")
var s7 = document.getElementById("s7")
var s8 = document.getElementById("s8")
var s9 = document.getElementById("s9")
var s = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9];
var comChoice = 0;
var clickScore = 0;


function myGame() {
  var beginer = prompt("Кто будет начинать ? Нажмите 'ОК' - если хотите начать первым ", "Я");
}
myGame()




function click1(element) {


  if (element.innerText == "") {
    clickScore++

    if (clickScore % 2 == 1) {
      element.style.cursor = "default"
      element.style.color = "white"
      element.style.fontSize = "40px"
      element.style.textAlign = "center"
      element.innerHTML = "X"
    } else {
      element.style.cursor = "default"
      element.style.color = "white"
      element.style.fontSize = "40px"
      element.style.textAlign = "center"
      element.innerHTML = "O"
    }
  } else {
    alert("Ячейка  уже занята")
  }
  computerTurn()
  if (proverka()) {
    alert("Game Over")
  }
}


function proverka() {

  if (s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML && s4.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "X" || s1.innerHTML == s4.innerHTML && s4.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s3.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "X" || s3.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s1.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s9.innerHTML && s9.innerHTML == "X" || s3.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s1.innerHTML == s2.innerHTML && s2.innerHTML == s3.innerHTML && s3.innerHTML == "X" || s1.innerHTML == s2.innerHTML && s2.innerHTML == s7.innerHTML && s7.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s4.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s6.innerHTML && s6.innerHTML == "X" || s4.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s6.innerHTML && s6.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s7.innerHTML == s8.innerHTML && s8.innerHTML == s9.innerHTML && s9.innerHTML == "X" || s7.innerHTML == s8.innerHTML && s8.innerHTML == s9.innerHTML && s9.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s3.innerHTML == s6.innerHTML && s6.innerHTML == s9.innerHTML && s9.innerHTML == "X" || s3.innerHTML == s6.innerHTML && s6.innerHTML == s9.innerHTML && s9.innerHTML == "O") return true;
  if (s8.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s2.innerHTML && s2.innerHTML == "X" || s8.innerHTML == s5.innerHTML && s5.innerHTML == s2.innerHTML && s2.innerHTML == "O") return true;
}


function computerTurn() {
  comChoice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
  console.log(s[comChoice].innerHTML)
  if (s[comChoice].innerHTML == "") {
    s[comChoice].innerHTML == "Y"
  } else {
    console.log(s[comChoice].innerHTML)
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
table {
  margin: 12% auto;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
tr {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.qar {
  {
    cursor: default;
  }
```

```html
<table width="300px" height="300px" border="5px">
  <tr>
    <td id="s1" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s2" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s3" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="s4" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s5" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s6" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="s7" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s8" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
    <td id="s9" onclick="click1(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44333/discussion-on-question-by--function-computerturn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберем возможность случайного выбора уже заполненой клетки:

```
function computerTurn() {
  var empties = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].innerHTML == "")
      empties.push(s[i]);
  }
  if (empties.length > 0) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * empties.length);
    empties[index].innerHTML = "Y";
  }
}
```

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо (кстати только что) 
так и не понял как правильно выделить код ՝function computerTurn(){
var comChoice=0;
  comChoice =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) );
   if(s[comChoice].innerText == 'X'||s[comChoice].innerText =='O'){
   console.log(s[comChoice].innerText)
  computerTurn(); } 
  else{ 
   s[comChoice].innerHTML="O"
    s[comChoice].style.cursor= "default"
     s[comChoice].style.color="white"
      s[comChoice].style.fontSize="40px"
       s[comChoice].style.textAlign="center" }
}՝

Comment: @Тигран, в комментарии код лучше вообще не вставлять. [По поводу выделения кода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3286/%D0%90-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85/3287#3287)

Comment: @Grundy ,понял , спасибо